# CreateView doesn't create anything in Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I'm trying to do a CreateView that registers a series of details of a race in Django.

views.py:

```
class RegistrarDetalles(CreateView):
    model = DetallesCarrera
    second_model = Carrera
    form_class = RegistrarDetallesForm
    template_name = "carrera/detallesC.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('detalleC')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        context = super(RegistrarDetalles, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['carrera'] = Carrera.objects.get(id=pk)
        return context

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('detalleC', kwargs={'pk': self.object.id_carr})
```

models.py:

```
class DetallesCarrera(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    numero = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    id_carr = models.ForeignKey(Carrera, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id_caba = models.ForeignKey(Caballo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id_jock = models.ForeignKey(Jockey, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    posicion = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

forms.py:

```
class RegistrarDetallesForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = DetallesCarrera

        fields = [
            'id',
            'id_carr',
            'id_caba',
            'id_jock',
        ]

        widgets = {
            'id': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'id_carr': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control','id':'uno'}),
            'id_caba': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'id_jock': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

urls.py:

```
        path('listaCarr/<pk>/detalleC/agregar', login_required(views.RegistrarDetalles.as_view()), name='RegDetallCr'),
```

The form within the html template:

```
    <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="input-group form-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-id-card"></i></span>
            </div>
            <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Id" name="id" onblur="this.value=(document.getElementById('uno').value+'-'+a">
            -->
            {{ form.id }}
            {{ form.id.errors }}
        </div>                               
        <div class="input-group form-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-id-card"></i></span>
            </div>    
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Id Carrera" name="id_carr" value="{{ carrera.id }}" disabled>                                
            {{ form.id_carr.errores }}
        </div>

        <div class="input-group form-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-clock"></i></span>
            </div>
            {{ form.id_caba }}
            {{ form.id_caba.errors }}
        </div>

        <div class="input-group form-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-list-ol"></i></span>
            </div>
            {{ form.id_jock }}
            {{ form.id_jock.errors }}
        </div>

        <div class="input-group form-group d-none">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-list-ol"></i></span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Numero" name="numero" value="1" disabled>                                
            {{ form.numero.errors }}
        </div>

        <div class="input-group form-group d-none">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-list-ol"></i></span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Posicion" name="posicion" value="0" disabled>                                
            {{ form.posicion.errors }}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-warning w-100" type="submit">Incluir</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

It happens that when I access the page itself, the data loads normally and I can do the selection I need, as shown below, but when I click the Incluir button, it doesn't do anything, apparently just reloads the page without inserting it.

[It deploys with no problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwfWs.png)

It doesn't show the input for either Posicion and Numero because I want them to be updated in a different view.

Comment: Shouldn't it be UpdateView instead of CreateView?

Comment: I'm trying to create a unique record in a model named DetallesCarrera, not updating it yet

Comment: Ah, now I see. Does it make a POST request on submit? Can you see it in server console/browser network info?

Comment: I get both the GET and POST:

[10/Feb/2019 17:12:09] "GET /jornada/listaCarr/2-2019-02-10-/detalleC/agregar HTTP/1.1" 200 16527
[10/Feb/2019 17:12:14] "POST /jornada/listaCarr/2-2019-02-10-/detalleC/agregar HTTP/1.1" 200 16537